# JS valide form for a value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

im trying to create a html + JS form .. ive managed to make it work as i wanted.. but i wanted to add one more field into it which im not sure how to do it..
im not good at js so need help.

what im trying to do is.. that when user fills in the form.. one of the field should validate a promo code before submit.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function get(y){
        return document.getElementById(y).value;
    }
    function getResponse(){
        $.get("process.php", { name: get('name'), email: get('email'), postcode: get('postcode'), phone: get('phone'), postcode: get('fbcode') },
           function(data){
             if(data.status === false || data.status === 'false'){
                 return errorMsg(data.message);
             }else{
                errorMsg(data.message);
                setTimeout(" offerDownloadAndClose()", 4000); 
             }
           }, "json");
    }
    function errorMsg(msg){
        $('#status').html(msg);
        $('#status').slideDown('slow');
        setTimeout("doHide('#status')", 3000);
    }
    function doHide(t){
        $(t).slideUp('slow');   
    }
    function offerDownloadAndClose(){
        doHide('#fancybox-wrap, #fancybox-overlay');
        window.location = 'process.php?file=true';
    }
    function validnum(evt){
        var charCode;
        charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
        if ((charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || charCode == 46 || charCode == 127 || charCode == 8)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

</script>
```

i need to add one more field with facebook promo code.. so say our code is FaceCode1, when user fills in the form.. it validate the field with this value.. if the code is FaceCode1 it will process otherwise give error to fill it out.

so it  should be something like

```
function validcode{
if value=FaceCode1 
{return true;
}
else{
return false;
}
}
```

but i dont know how to create the value to specific code to check..
please if someone can help me on this.. would really appreciate it.
thanks.

Comment: could you provide the html and css too? preferably in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?
http://jsfiddle.net/davidchase03/QXGPD/

```
function validate() {
    var value = $('.promo').val();
    if (value === 'FaceCode1') {
        alert('all good')
    } else {
        alert('wrong')
    }
}

$('button').click(function(){
    validate();
});
```

let me know
-David

Comment: Hi,i thought it would work.. but i tried it on my page but the text area wont let me add anything in it.. if i post my whole code.. can you please have a look at it?

Comment: sure post your code inside a jsfiddle, jsbin or on here if neither options works

Comment: are you trying to validate as the person types the promo code or after they enter without clicking a button to submit?

Comment: when user click on submit.. it validates all the fields.. and if everything is in place then it starts the download as you can see in the process.php

Comment: the reason i ask is because you have keypress events that you are trying to use to validate the form, what are you using the keypress to do?

Comment: http://codepen.io/davidchase/pen/znsEj i can modify the fields to your needs and on success download any pdf with php

Comment: can u check the jsfidle files and tell me why the promo text box is not letting me type anything in it? everything else is working just fine.

Comment: sure just remove return inside of the inline js `onkeypress="return validcode(event)` to `onkeypress="validcode(event)`

Comment: can u show me here:`  function validnum(evt){
  var charCode;
  charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
  if ((charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57) || charCode == 46 || charCode == 127 || charCode == 8)
  {
   return true;
  }
  else{
   return false;
  }
 }
 function validcode(evt){
  var value = $('.promo').val();
  charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
  if (value === 'FaceCode1') {
   return true;
  }
  else{
   return false;
  }
 }`

Comment: `<p><input type="text" id="phone" class="input-text" placeholder="Telephone" onkeypress="return validnum(event)" /></p>` that prevented you from typing in the fields because of the return.

Comment: tried. but it didnt work.. its letting me type now but still shows error to fill the promo code field